# Getting two issues while using stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, primary-key, temp-tables

Below is the sample code of my Stored Procedure in which I am working on for interest calculation. This code is not executable because according to finding its getting issue while defining creating temporary table block before the cursor declaration but if I define same thing recently after cursor declaration then it's executing successfully.

1- My question is I am using that table inside cursor so I must have to define after cursor or I have missed anything ??

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_interest_calculation_test`(
    IN sub_type CHAR(1)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE s_ledger_id INT;
    DECLARE s_start, s_end, s_tran INT DEFAULT 0;

    **DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_interest;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_interest(
        id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        ledger_id INT UNSIGNED,
        dr_amount INT,
        cr_amount INT,
        balance INT
    );**

    DECLARE cur_saving_acc CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 1;

    OPEN cur_saving_acc;

    SET s_end = (SELECT FOUND_ROWS());

    WHILE s_start<s_end DO
    FETCH cur_saving_acc INTO s_ledger_id;

     INSERT INTO tmp_interest(ledger_id)
     SELECT s_ledger_id;

     SELECT * FROM tmp_interest;

     /*Interest calculation logic ends here */
     SET s_start = s_start+1;

     END WHILE;

    CLOSE cur_saving_acc;

END
```

2- After successful execution of above stored procedure (defining temporary table after cursor declaration), I got the following issue when I call the SP:

```
CALL sp_interest_calculation_test ('A');
```

"Error Code : 1075
Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"

It is because I missed to define id as primary key so I simply changed column with

```
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

I am using stored procedure in MySQL first time and it was hectic for me to fix the above issue so can you please describe me the above issues and their reasons and it there anyway to define auto number column without defining that as primary key ?

Note: Parameter sub_type is not used anywhere  and there isn't more operations performed within cursor in the sample code though I am dealing with heavy interest calculation inside the block.

Thank you very much in advance and hope all you will pay some interest in this question. (I didn't find anything exact for these issues). I am also looking for alternatives of it, simply I have to calculate debit,credit,balance for each ledger, I tried it by without loop in single query but execution never ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `DECLARE` is permitted only inside a `BEGIN ... END` compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.
>
> Declarations must follow a certain order. Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations. Variable and condition declarations must appear before cursor or handler declarations.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html

That's the restriction.

Now, the workaround: **add a nested  `BEGIN ... END` block.**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ...
BEGIN
  DECLARE ... INT ... -- variable
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE... -- following the declarations, no more declarations allowed, unless...
  BEGIN -- resets the scope, changes the rules, allows more declarations
    DECLARE ... INT ... -- variables
    DECLARE ... CURSOR ...
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER ...
    OPEN ...
    ...
  END;
END $$
```

All the variables in the outer block are still in scope in the inner block, unless another variable in the inner block has a conflicting name.

A `HANDLER` in the outer block is also in scope for signals in the inner block, unless a conflicting handler is declared there, in which case the inner handler will catch the exception and the outer handle will catch anything throw by the inner handler, including a `RESIGNAL`.

Multiple nesting levels are allowed.  The size of the [`thread_stack`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_stack) might be a factor, but the documentation is unclear.  I've been running 262,144 byte thread stacks since before it was made the default, and have never encountered a limit.

Comment: Nice answer Michael

Answer (score 1):

Some notes about what is possible with `AUTO_INCREMENT` setup:

```
create table t1
(   ai int not null auto_increment,
    b int primary key
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
-- Error 1075: AI must be a key

create table t2
(   ai int not null auto_increment,
    b int primary key,
    key(ai)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

-- This is successful

create table t3
(   ai int not null auto_increment,
    b int primary key,
    c int not null,
    key(ai,c)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
-- This is successful

create table t4
(   ai int not null auto_increment,
    b int primary key,
    c int not null,
    key(c,ai)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
-- Error 1075: AI must be a key (ai is not left-most in composite)

create table t5
(   ai int auto_increment primary key,
    b int not null,
    c int not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
-- Success: This is the PREDOMINANT way of doing it

create table t6
(   ai int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    b int not null,
    c int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(c,ai)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
-- Error 1075: AI must be a key (ai is not left-most in PK)

create table t7
(   ai int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    b int not null,
    c int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(ai,c)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
-- Success

create table t8
(   ai int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    b int not null,
    c int not null,
    KEY(ai),
    KEY(c,ai)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
insert t8(b,c) values(1,2);
insert t8(b,c) values(33,44);
select * from t8;
+----+----+----+
| ai | b  | c  |
+----+----+----+
|  1 |  1 |  2 |
|  2 | 33 | 44 |
+----+----+----+
```

Note ENGINE=MyISAM behaves differently, such as allowing the AI to be non-left most.

Stored Proc:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_interest_calculation_test`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_interest_calculation_test`(
    IN sub_type CHAR(1)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE l_ledger_id INT;
    DECLARE dr_sum DECIMAL(14,2) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE l_dr_amount, l_cr_amount, l_balance DECIMAL(14,2);
    DECLARE cur_saving_acc CURSOR 
       FOR SELECT ledger_id, dr_amount, cr_amount, balance FROM tmp_interest order by id;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_interest;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_interest(
        id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        ledger_id INT UNSIGNED,
        dr_amount DECIMAL(14,2),
        cr_amount DECIMAL(14,2),
        balance DECIMAL(14,2),
        KEY(id)
    );
    INSERT tmp_interest (ledger_id,dr_amount,cr_amount,balance) VALUES
    (101,100,0,200),(102,140,0,340),(103,0,50,290);

    OPEN cur_saving_acc;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur_saving_acc INTO l_ledger_id, l_dr_amount, l_cr_amount, l_balance;

        IF done THEN
          LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        SET dr_sum=dr_sum+l_dr_amount;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur_saving_acc;
    SELECT CONCAT('sum of debits=',dr_sum) as outCol;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Test:

```
call sp_interest_calculation_test('s');
+----------------------+
| outCol               |
+----------------------+
| sum of debits=240.00 |
+----------------------+
```

The above `CURSOR` setup is the proper way to do a `FETCH` loop with a `LEAVE` and a handler. Cursor loops are finicky. Don't directly mess with the `done` variable. You are trusting the `FETCH` and the handler with it. So let it deal with `done` all on its own.

MySQL Manual Page on [CURSORS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html). Also note that Cursors perform like junk. They are fun to play with. They can get you out of a tricky situation. But you bring performance to its knees when you use them.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have used this pattern first in this logic but it will create so many problem, sometimes it ends during the execution automatically and have seen problem within few executions. So that I have changed to above and it's working fine since 2-3 months but I don't think CURSOR in MySQL is trustworthy. What you say ? if anyone suggest me the alternative then I will change the logic, let me mention it in my question, it's also tedious for debugging. +1 for your very helpful information.

Comment: I would never use the pattern different than the one I showed and the one in the manual. If you ever want me to review any of your stuff come on by [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) chat and ping me. I certainly would never use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in that `while` and that is so not best practices

Comment: Then I am sure I missed something there the difference is only SET done = TRUE; (your) and SET done = 1; mine, and same way in the if statement to LEAVE. is this make any sense ? and sure I will ping you very soon then I will describe the whole scenario and my requirement. Thanks Again

Comment: which is why I said "Cursors perform like junk". High performance db engines excel at sets and indexes. People that use cursors are either completely new to sql and can't do sets and relations, or they are in the middle of something very tricky and can't find a better way. The high performace engine gets destroyed when people want to put their own steps and procedural mind into it. I've been there. I know why people use cursors. Best to get them off it. Especially when processing big data.